# One long beep and two short beeps after ASUS BIOS Update

Tags: bios

Motherboard: ASUS PRIME B350-PLUS

RAM: Corsair Vengeance 1x16GB 2400MHz

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 1500X

GPU (current): EVGA 950 GTX SC

So I've recently purchased a new GPU and I wanted to make sure everything was up to date on my computer.
I checked the ASUS support site for new BIOS updates and there happened to be one for my motherboard.

I used the ASUS AI Suite 3 EZUpdate utility to perform the BIOS update for me. It began the process, then restarted, then began the BIOS flash, which it completed successfully. It then displayed a message requesting to restart the computer, which I accepted. I have done this same process a few times before in the past with BIOS updates and it has worked with no problems. However this time, once it had restarted, there was no video output and the computer does not get to POST.

The speaker beeps with one long beep and two short beeps, and according to ASUS this is a memory error. However, the beeps do not loop, they only happen once. I tested my RAM and that is not the problem. I believe the BIOS update has caused a problem.

Things I have tried since then:

- reset CMOS by shorting pins. No result.
- taken battery out and left for half an hour. No result.
- taken every component out other than CPU and ram. No result.
- placed RAM in each slot (4 slots total) and tried. No result.
- put the updated BIOS file on a USB stick and placed that in the correct USB port to attempt the auto recovery. No result.

By no result I mean nothing has changed and I don't get any video output.

Is the motherboard bricked? ASUS support was not helpful and recommend I replace every part except the motherboard.

Comment: Have you tried to boot with a single memory module?

Comment: Yes I have booted it with a single module, and tried that for each channel.

Comment: Did you try to use an older BIOS? Also your board might have a recovery BIOS available (check the manual).